# mpi4py Allgatherv for matrices

Tags: matrix, mpi4py

I have a matrix `x` of size `(n0,N)` and `(n1,N)`, for two different MPI processes, repsectively. I am trying to gather them to a single matrix, defined on both processes.

Here's my attempt:

```
"""
run with: mpiexec -n 2 python test.py

"""

from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np


comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD

n0=3
n1=4
N=2


if comm.Get_rank()==0:
    x=np.ones((n0,N),dtype=np.float64)
else:
    x=2.0*np.ones((n1,N),dtype=np.float64)


x_gathered = np.zeros((n0+n1,N), x.dtype  )


comm.Allgatherv([x,   MPI.DOUBLE], [x_gathered,  MPI.DOUBLE], )

print(x_gathered)
```

I am getting an error:

```
MPIR_Localcopy(46)..........................: Message truncated; 64 bytes received but buffer size is 56
```

I noticed that when I set the two sizes `n0=n1`, then the code runs properly. Can someone explain to me why I can't use `Allgatherv` in the case of different `n0` and `n1`, and how this `Allgatherv`-operation can be eventually achieved using `mpi4py`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out: `Allgatherv` requires extra arguments for `sendcounts` and `displacements`, see [here](https://materials.jeremybejarano.com/MPIwithPython/collectiveCom.html#scatterv-and-gatherv).

```
"""
mpiexec -n 2 python test.py

"""

from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
from sys import getsizeof


comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD

n0=4
n1=3
N=2


if comm.Get_rank()==0:
    x=np.ones((n0,N,),dtype=np.float64)
else:
    x=2.0*np.ones((n1,N,),dtype=np.float64)


x_gathered = np.zeros(((n0+n1)*N,),dtype=np.float64  )

sendcountes=(n0*N,n1*N)
displacements=(0,n0*N)

comm.Allgatherv([x, MPI.DOUBLE], [x_gathered, sendcountes, displacements, MPI.DOUBLE], )

print(x_gathered)
```

Comment: Yes, and keep in mind that sendcounts and displacements should be scaled with the row size, because NumPy stores arrays row-major in memory